# IIS Server Farm Health API?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, iis, iis-6, server-farm

we have a Windows Server 2008 R2 running 4 virtual servers on a Server Farm, but currently the only way we're able to check the health of the servers is by RDP'ing on to the server that manages them and going into IIS. We would like to be able to have a webpage where we can see the healf of the servers and see which ones are available or unavailable.

Is there a way for us, to interact with the server (potentially via an API) and get information about the servers in our C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at your disposal for monitoring IIS and related services remotely:

- [Web Service Counters for the WWW Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786217%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Internet Information Services Global Counters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738536%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Performance Counters for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

You can check out these counter values through windows's [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749115.aspx), which provides a fair user interface, or use the following C# code to develop your own monitoring tool:

```
var category = "Web Service";
var counter = "Current Connections";
var instance = "_Total";
var server = "192.168.0.1";

var perf = new PerformanceCounter(category , counter , instance , server);

int connections = (int)perf.NextValue();
```